# Diagram image with clickable areas as svg paths

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, responsive-design

**Using React, I have created an app that allows users to select a muscle on a diagram of the human body to view information about that muscle.**

[image]

As a next step, I would now like to remove the buttons, and instead allow the user to click the muscles on the diagram directly. Additionally, I would like to highlight muscles as the user hovers their mouse over them, as well as highlight the currently selected muscle.

Originally, my plan was to slice up the current diagram image into one image per muscle and then position each muscle image absolutely on top of the current diagram image with a click handler that swaps out the regular version of the image for a highlighted version when hovered or clicked.

However, I am wondering if this is something that I could use **svg paths** for? How would that work in React?

---

**Current Code**

```
// BodyImage component
export class BodyImage extends Component {

    // when the component renders
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="BodyImage">

                <img 
                    className="body body-front"
                    alt="Front of the human body" 
                    src={require('../assets/images/body-front.png')} 
                />

                <div className="overlay">
                    { this.props.muscles.map( muscle => {
                        return (
                            <div key={muscle.id}>
                                { muscle.image && muscle.image.file
                                ? (                                    
                                <button 
                                    onClick={this.props.handleClickSelectMuscle} 
                                    style={muscle.image.position}
                                    value={muscle.id}
                                >
                                    <img 
                                        src={require('../assets/images/' + muscle.image.file )} 
                                        alt={muscle.h1} 
                                    />
                                </button>              
                                )
                                : null
                                }
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>  

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using an image tag you can use SVG tag directly and wrap your paths with `a` tag or `Link` tag whichever suits you. Read more about this here https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/